# Update remote MySQL database upon changes in local SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, mysql, data-synchronization

I have a Web store running with MySQL on the remote host. And I have inventory management software using Microsoft SQL Server on my local system.

I want to update product stock in the web store when product stock changes in my inventory management software.

Can I do this with a SQL query?

Comment: The remote host is PHP with mySQL or your are running a CMS like WordPress?

Comment: How exactly are you changing data in the local inventory management software? Is it possible to change that front end so that it simply writes changes to both systems simultaneously?

Comment: The remote host runs Opencart. When I prepare an invoice in inventory management software the stock will be reduced. Same to be reduced in Opencart.